# Vectorize Memoized Function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I've got a dataframe of ~10,000,000 rows that requires an operation on one of the columns. The number of unique values in the column is about two orders of magnitude lower, so at the moment I'm doing the transform by applying a memoized function.

```
new = [foo(x) for x in df.column])
index = np.where(new > df.other, new, df.other)
df.set_index(index)

@memoized
def foo(x):
    if x > 0:
        bar = -1
    else:
        bar = 10
    x *= bar
    return x
```

The sheer size of the dataframe is means that calculating `new` is still taking longer than I'd like.

Is there any way to use vecorization to speed this step up? Or any other tricks that aren't vectorization?

Comment: Have you tried to benchmark the list comprehension against a call to apply (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).
You may also have a look at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html.

Comment: I did. Forget the exact results, but the list comprehension was significantly faster.

Comment: Ok, then having recourse to cython may be interesting as suggested in https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, here is a vectorized approach:

```
col = df.column # This is based on your code and is assumed to to return
# a column but I think you should use indexing to get a column like df['colname']

cond1 = col > 0
cond2 = ~cond1
col[cond1] = col[cond1] * -1
col[cond2] = col[cond2] * 10
```